# Spring Security OAuth2 | InsufficientAuthenticationException

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to build an OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Security OAuth2 (2.0.6.RELEASE).

This is how my relevant configuration looks:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration
     * .AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
     * #configure(org.springframework.security
     * .oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers
     * .AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer)
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration
     * .AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
     * #configure(org.springframework.security
     * .oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer)
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {

        // OAuth2 CLIENT CONFIGURATION !!!!!
        clients.inMemory().withClient("sambhav").secret("sambhav")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("openid", "all").redirectUris("http:localhost:9001");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration
     * .AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
     * #configure(org.springframework.security
     * .oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers
     * .AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer)
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
            throws Exception {
        super.configure(security);
    }
}
```

Using Spring Boot embedded jetty, during startup I see that OAuth2 endpoints do get registered in my logs.

While trying to hit (using Postman) the /oauth/authorize POST endpoint with `client_id=sambhav,response_type=code,redirect_uri=http://localhost:9001,scope=all,` I am getting 500 error in response with the following error:-

```
{"timestamp":1423055109697,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException","message":"User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.","path":"/oauth/authorize"}
```

Looking at the logs, I can see that there is check for authentication in class `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint` 's method `authorize`:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/authorize")
    public ModelAndView authorize(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters,
            SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {

        // Pull out the authorization request first, using the OAuth2RequestFactory. All further logic should
        // query off of the authorization request instead of referring back to the parameters map. The contents of the
        // parameters map will be stored without change in the AuthorizationRequest object once it is created.
        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = getOAuth2RequestFactory().createAuthorizationRequest(parameters);

        Set<String> responseTypes = authorizationRequest.getResponseTypes();

        if (!responseTypes.contains("token") && !responseTypes.contains("code")) {
            throw new UnsupportedResponseTypeException("Unsupported response types: " + responseTypes);
        }

        if (authorizationRequest.getClientId() == null) {
            throw new InvalidClientException("A client id must be provided");
        }

        try {
             // THIS check causes the problem
            if (!(principal instanceof Authentication) || !((Authentication) principal).isAuthenticated()) {
                throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                        "User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.");
            }
```

**PROBLEM**

Why is an already established Authentication required for the authorize step?

Whose authorization (user or client) is required? How do I do that? Using client_id/client_secret combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `authorization_code` grant gives a client access to a resource server if the user (aka resource owner) allows it.

You are trying to access the page where the user can grant authorization to the client but you are not logged in as a user so Spring Security can't know *who* is supposed to authorize the client (sambhav) in your example.

Comment: I wan to provide my own custom SSO for my application(s) (similiar to Google login). What grant type should I use and what should be the overall workflow.

Comment: That heavily depends on your client application. I found [this site](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) to be very helpful to get an understanding over the different grant types.